# how to avoid screen lock in a cellphone? r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to keep some action rolling in the background of the app to prevent the phone screen from automatically locking?I mean some way to avoid the automatic screen lock that occurs on cell phones

Answer (score 0):

R works normally in a single thread, meaning that if you have some long task running, the shiny interface will not be updated until the task is completed (wherever the user is on a mobile device or not).

You should probably explore the use of the libraries `future` and `promises` in conjunction with shiny in order to split the workload between different threads and keep the user interface responsive.

[Using promises with Shiny](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html) is a good primer on the subject.